# Jetty ALPN has not been properly configured - Hadoop / Google Bigtable

Tags: java, jetty, google-cloud-bigtable

Do anyone know how to resolve Jetty ALPN not properly configured error, when I attempting to connect to Google Cloud BigTable?

> Blockquote
>   2015-12-11 19:53:15,056 INFO  [main] grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId crawl-corpus-app, zoneId us-central1-c, clusterId crawl-corpus, on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
>   java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)................................................................................................................................................
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jetty ALPN has not been properly configured.
>       at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.(BigtableSession.java:243)
>       at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.(BigtableSession.java:232)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:128)
>       at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_1.BigtableConnection.(BigtableConnection.java:42)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection;
   try {
       connection  = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add a VM option for Jetty alpn-boot.

```
 -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Users\cleuer\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\alpn\alpn-boot\8.1.3.v20150130\alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when netty jar version is mismatched with other jars.

If you received an error message "ALPN is not configured properly" or "Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured", it most likely means that:

1) ALPN related dependencies are either not present in the classpath

2) or that there is a classpath conflict

3) or that a wrong version is used due to dependency management

4) or you are on an unsupported platform (e.g., 32-bit OS).

Please see gRPC troubleshooting guide https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting.

Hope it helps.